# How to convert a string value to the correct reflect.Kind in go?

Tags: string, go, reflection, type-conversion

Is there a generic helper method in Go to convert a `string` to the correct value based on `reflect.Kind`?

Or do I need to implement the switch over all kinds myself?

I have a value like "143" as a string and a reflect.Value with kind "UInt16" and like to convert that string value and set it into the UInt16 value of my struct.

My current code looks like:

```
func setValueFromString(v reflect.Value, strVal string) error {
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        val, err := strconv.ParseInt(strVal, 0, 64)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if v.OverflowInt(val) {
            return errors.New("Int value too big: " + strVal)
        }
        v.SetInt(val)
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
        val, err := strconv.ParseUint(strVal, 0, 64)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if v.OverflowUint(val) {
            return errors.New("UInt value too big: " + strVal)
        }
        v.SetUint(val)
    case reflect.Float32:
        val, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strVal, 32)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        v.SetFloat(val)
    case reflect.Float64:
        val, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strVal, 64)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        v.SetFloat(val)
    case reflect.String:
        v.SetString(strVal)
    case reflect.Bool:
        val, err := strconv.ParseBool(strVal)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        v.SetBool(val)
    default:
        return errors.New("Unsupported kind: " + v.Kind().String())
    }
    return nil
}
```

This works already, but I wonder if this is already implemented somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Edit:** Answer to the original question ("how to obtain a `reflect.Kind` from its `string` representation") is at the end. Answer to your edited question follows:*

---

What you're doing is the fastest and "safest". If you don't want to hassle with that big `switch`, you may take advantage of e.g. the [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package which already contains this `switch` to decode values from JSON string (in [`encoding/json/decode.go`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go), unexported function `literalStore()`).

Your decoding function could look like this:

```
func Set(v interface{}, s string) error {
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), v)
}
```

A simple call to [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal). Using / testing it:

```
{
    var v int
    err := Set(&v, "1")
    fmt.Println(v, err)
}
{
    var v int
    err := Set(&v, "d")
    fmt.Println(v, err)
}
{
    var v uint32
    err := Set(&v, "3")
    fmt.Println(v, err)
}
{
    var v bool
    err := Set(&v, "true")
    fmt.Println(v, err)
}
{
    var v float32
    err := Set(&v, `5.1`)
    fmt.Println(v, err)
}
{
    var v string
    err := Set(&v, strconv.Quote("abc"))
    fmt.Println(v, err)
}
```

One thing to note: when you want to pass a `string`, that must be quoted, e.g. with [`strconv.Quote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote). Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uCjkDaKUux)):

```
1 <nil>
0 invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value
3 <nil>
true <nil>
5.1 <nil>
abc <nil>
```

If you don't want to require quoted strings (which just complicates things), you may build it into the `Set()` function:

```
func Set(v interface{}, s string) error {
    if t := reflect.TypeOf(v); t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr &&
        t.Elem().Kind() == reflect.String {
        s = strconv.Quote(s)
    }
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), v)
}
```

And then you may call it with the address of a `string` variable and a `string` value unquoted:

```
var v string
err := Set(&v, "abc")
fmt.Println(v, err)
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/af5NWySkZk).

---

*Answer to the original question: how to obtain a `reflect.Kind` from its `string` representation:*

Declaration of [`reflect.Kind`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind):

```
type Kind uint
```

The different values of `reflect.Kind`s are constants:

```
const (
    Invalid Kind = iota
    Bool
    Int
    Int8
    // ...
    Struct
    UnsafePointer
)
```

And the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package provides only a single method for the `reflect.Kind()` type:

```
func (k Kind) String() string
```

So as it stands, you cannot obtain a `reflect.Kind` from its `string` representation (only the reverse direction is possible by using the [`Kind.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind.String) method). But it's not that hard to provide this functionality.

What we'll do is we build a `map` from all the kinds:

```
var strKindMap = map[string]reflect.Kind{}
```

We init it like this:

```
func init() {
    for k := reflect.Invalid; k <= reflect.UnsafePointer; k++ {
        strKindMap[k.String()] = k
    }
}
```

<sup>This is possible and correct because constants are initialized using [`iota`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota) which evaluates to successive untyped integer constants, and the first value is `reflect.Invalid` and the last is `reflect.UnsafePointer`.</sup>

And now you can obtain `reflect.Kind` from its `string` representation by simply indexing this map. A helper function which does that:

```
func strToKind(s string) reflect.Kind {
    k, ok := strKindMap[s]
    if !ok {
        return reflect.Invalid
    }
    return k
}
```

And we're done. Testing / using it:

```
fmt.Printf("All: %#v\n", strKindMap)

for _, v := range []string{"Hey", "uint8", "ptr", "func", "chan", "interface"} {
    fmt.Printf("String: %q, Kind: %v (%#v)\n", v, strToKind(v), strToKind(v))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IKRedScwo1)):

```
All: map[string]reflect.Kind{"int64":0x6, "uint8":0x8, "uint64":0xb, "slice":0x17, "uintptr":0xc, "int8":0x3, "array":0x11, "interface":0x14, "unsafe.Pointer":0x1a, "complex64":0xf, "complex128":0x10, "int":0x2, "uint":0x7, "int16":0x4, "uint16":0x9, "map":0x15, "bool":0x1, "int32":0x5, "ptr":0x16, "string":0x18, "func":0x13, "struct":0x19, "invalid":0x0, "uint32":0xa, "float32":0xd, "float64":0xe, "chan":0x12}
String: "Hey", Kind: invalid (0x0)
String: "uint8", Kind: uint8 (0x8)
String: "ptr", Kind: ptr (0x16)
String: "func", Kind: func (0x13)
String: "chan", Kind: chan (0x12)
String: "interface", Kind: interface (0x14)
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I will edit the question as well. I have a value like "143" as a string and a reflect.Value with kind "UInt16" and like to convert that string value and set it into the UInt16 value of my struct